# web3 error: private key length is invalid

Tags: web3js, rinkeby

I was trying to create my own wallet on etherum test network Rinkeby. When I successfully created wallet:

```
const newAccount = await web3.eth.accounts.create()
```

and got wallet address 0x267634Db8890Ad1F05e214dD9De961484c078895 
and wallet private key 0x27fc2c9ba1cba2c519f5423ab4dde5777cfe1f4d462c5bb64ba223a570f3efeb

I added some test ether on my new account (3 ether) , and tried to send some value on other account which I was also create

```
const main = async () => {
  let nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
  let gasPrices = await getCurrentGasPrices()
  let details = {
    "to": DESTINATION_WALLET_ADDRESS,
    "value": amountToSend,
    "gas": 21000,
    "gasPrice": gasPrices.low * 1000000000, 
    "nonce": nonce,
    "chainId": 4,
  }
  const transaction = new EthereumTx(details, { chain: 'rinkeby', hardfork: 'petersburg' })
  await transaction.sign(Buffer.from(PRIVATE_KEY_DESTINATION_ACCOUNT, 'hex'))
  const serializedTransaction = await transaction.serialize()
  const transactionId = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex') )
  process.exit()
}

main()
```

but i got error message : "private key length is invalid", and when I cleared 0x from my private key I got other error "insufficient funds for gas * price + value"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: await transaction.sign(Buffer.from(PRIVATE_KEY_DESTINATION_ACCOUNT.substring(2), 'hex'))   should help

Comment: Or `slice(2)`...

Comment: I found solution ..I created wallet using command : web3.eth.accounts.create() ,but I forgot encrypt that wallet .. 
I added web3.eth.accounts.encrypt(privateKey, password), and now I can send etherium from that wallet

Comment: Also I had to remove 0x from my private key